# Self referencing foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, inheritance

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First to rebuild an application that used to run from an Access database. One of the requirements is that the new data schema should be auditable, that is it should show who created a record and who updated it and when etc.

I've created a base Entity class as follows:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedByUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a class that inherits from EntityTypeConfiguration as follows

```
public class BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : Entity
{
    Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName(typeof(T).Name + "Id");

    HasRequired(e => e.CreatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedById);
    HasOptional(e => e.UpdatedBy).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.UpdatedById);
}
```

Now I create configurations that inherit from BaseEntityTypeConfiguration for the rest of my business classes that inherit from my Entity class.

The problem comes when I try to make my User class inherit from entity as follows:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    // etc
}
```

I'll be adding a "ghost" user for records where the evidence isn't there to determine who created the record, but this ghost user will essentially be created by itself.

I'm getting the following error from Entity Framework when I try to add this ghost user:

```
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements or store-generated values.
```

There may be problems in my domain model that could be causing this error, but my theory is that it's down to this user that's trying to create itself in this instance.

Is having a self-referencing foreign key constraint problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PK is an identity column and you're setting the ghost user's `CreatedByUser` property with itself.  This causes a chicken/egg scenario - you need the `User.Id` value as the `User.CreatedById` value to insert the record into the DB table, but you don't know what `User.Id` is until after the record is inserted.

If you can be sure of the identity's seed value (EF seems to default to `1`), you can set the `CreatedByUserId` property to that value instead of `CreatedByUser`.

Otherwise, create your ghost user by executing a SQL statement allowing you to manually set the `Id` and `CreatedByUserId` fields to the same value then reseed the identity to `Id + 1`.

Example of the former:

```
public class UserWithCreatedBy
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CreatedById { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( "CreatedById" )]
    public UserWithCreatedBy CreatedBy { get; set; }
}


static void Main( string[] args )
{
    using( var db = new TestContext() )
    {
        var u = new UserWithCreatedBy();

        // doesn't work with identity
        //u.CreatedBy = u;

        // this will work as long as you know what the identity seed is
        // (whatever the next identity value will be)
        u.CreatedById = 1;

        db.UsersWithCreatedBy.Add( u );

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```